# SQL Server Performance Degradation - High Lazy writes/sec and free list stalls/sec

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, database-performance

I am supporting a customer of ours who has an enterprise edition of our web application living on virtualized servers at their location. They have 3 web servers and 1 DB server. All 4 servers are virtualized with vCenter and have Windows Server 2008 R2 installed.

The DB server is running SQL Server 2008 R2 with 36 GB of RAM, and separate drives for the DB, logs, backups, etc. (7 virtual in total) on a SAS setup, though the backups occur onto a SSD drive.

The web servers are 4 GB RAM each and load balanced. We have a few processes that import data from third parties into our application for end-users, but recently one of these processes have bottle-necked on the server and caused issues. A process that *should* take hours takes days, and often times fails out, so I have to manually queue up the process in SQL and let it run.

After much investigation, I'm at a loss as to what the issue it. I've confirmed all of the Web Application settings are the same as our hosted environment, which houses customers much larger than this and our DB server is more robust, but the overall load onto the server is great.

Some metrics that I have included cause me to worry about the processes that are actually occurring on the server. I've included these below but I am specifically worried about the Lazy writes/sec and free list stalls/sec, as to me this is indicating that the process is overloading the server in memory and dumping the page to hard disk, which would drive down performance. Is this correct? Can anyone give me ideas on where to go from here? The customer definitely is not liking the idea of adding more resources to the DB server, so I want to be able to prove, definitively, where the issue is at.

Since this is in a virtualized environment, could it also be that the resources just happen to be shared, driving down the performance of the VM and causing this to be flushed to the drive? Any help would be greatly appreciated. My hardware experience has met its limits and I am not a DBA, so I am trying to wrap my head around what all actually goes on in the background with SQL Server.

Thanks!

```
Buffer cache hit ratio           1363657/sec
Buffer cache hit ratio base      1363687/sec
Page lookups/sec                 28043473454/sec
Free list stalls/sec             621/sec
Free pages                       1438/sec
Total pages                      3932160/sec
Target pages                     3932160/sec
Database pages                   3846600/sec
Reserved pages                   0/sec
Stolen pages                     84122/sec
Lazy writes/sec                  77354/sec
Readahead pages/sec              15305687/sec
Page reads/sec                   16859120/sec
Page writes/sec                  7751703/sec
Checkpoint pages/sec             5408194/sec
AWE lookup maps/sec              0/sec
AWE stolen maps/sec              0/sec
AWE write maps/sec               0/sec
AWE unmap calls/sec              0/sec
AWE unmap pages/sec              0/sec
Page life expectancy             16434/sec
```

Comment: you'd better to ask this question on dba.stackexchange.com

Comment: flagged as should be closed because off topic - not development related. You did a good job in summarizing everything but the question is far too broad to be answered in an SO topic. You say the backup goes to ssd drive, but not even if the database is located on an ssd as well. In professional environments, i tend to just add more memory when the server hits the memory limit once. Also I require dedicated memory on VM hosts for debugging.

Comment: This was the answer to my question: https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/190594/138293

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Essentially, memory ballooning and shared memory / disks was the issue here. I could not see the VMWare host, but it was being used to scale up and use resources affecting the performance of the machine. I linked an answer to DBA stack exchange that helped me to identify the issue in a comment.